# OS environment variables in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, docker, environment-variables

I know about the environment.ts  files in Angular, but with those I end up comitting sensitive data to my git repo. In Java I can just refer to OS environment variables which I can set on my server.

In our company the CI dockers all our applications and pushes them into OpenShift, which means I don't have access to the file system, so I can not just put a production environment.ts there manually.

Does anyone have an idea how to get to the OS environment variables?

Comment: Through a webservice that'd need to be deployed on the same machine?

Comment: In our environment there only can be one deployment per virtual machine and there is also only one port available. It is kind of restricted when it comes to stuff like that.

Comment: so you create one package for all environments?

Comment: But then I could also just hardcode my data in the first application. Our CI just pulls the code from the git repository, dockerizes it and deploys it into an OpenShift application. Two repositories -> two applications with two different routes and URLs

Comment: Check this out https://blog.usejournal.com/system-environment-variables-in-angular-1f4a922c7b4c

Answer (score 1):

If you are bundling your angular application with webpack, you can use [webpack.DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "some_variable": JSON.stringify(process.env.SOME_ENV_VAR || "my_default_value")
    })
]
```

Then you can reference "some_variable" in your angular application. You can declare them in your `typings.d.ts` file so they are recognized.

```
declare const some_variable: string
```

You can always have a web service that can serve you these variables through api calls as well.

Comment: You can also check a video tutorial explaining how to use webpack.DefinePlugin with Angular 7 at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BU5G_i1J5CA

Answer (score 1):

1. Have an API that serves the config, and retrieve that from angular

   ```
   app.get("/api/config/default", function(req, res) {
     res.send({
      a: process.env["A_VAR"]
     });
   })
   ```
2. Have your back-end generate the angular constants

   ```
   app.get("/generated-config.js", function(req, res) {
     res.send(
       "angular.module('myApp').constant('MY_CONFIG',"
        + "{'a': \"" + process.env["A_VAR"] + "\""
        + "})"
      );
   });
   ```

   For which you can use [ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-constant). 
   I like this approach better because blocking angular controllers and services that depend on this config becomes very easy. In my case, the back-end generates this file and serves it together with the rest of the static files.